# Render HTML without the extra "data-reactid" DOM attribute in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm doing something like this in one of my react.js files:

```
 render: function() { 
    var stuff = this.props.stuff;

    function getHtmlForKey(key_name, title) {
        var key_name = key_name.toLowerCase();
            return Object.keys(thing).filter(function(key) {
                return key && key.toLowerCase().indexOf(key_name) === 0;
            }).map(function(key, index) {
                var group_title = index === 0 ? title : '';
                if(profile[key] != null && thing[key] != "") {
                    return (
                        <span>
                        {group_title ? (
                            <li className="example-group-class">{group_title}</li>
                        ) : null }
                        <li key={key} className="example-class">
                            {thing[key]}
                        </li>
                        </span>
                    );
                }    
            }, this);
    }

    /** Grouping by keyword **/
    var group1 = getHtmlForKey('stuff1', 'Group Title 1');

    /** Return Facecards **/
    if (stuff) {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="media">
                    <div className="pull-left">
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.open}>
                            <img src={this.props.stuff} className="media" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="top">
                        {group1}
                    </div>
       }
}
```

When this renders it outputs something like:

```
  <li class="example-group-title" data-reactid=".0.0.2.0.$2083428221.0.1.0:0.0">Group Title</li>
```

In my other react.js file, i've got:

```
    var StuffApp = require('./components/StuffApp.react');

    ReactDOM.render(
    <StuffApp />,
     document.getElementById('main-content')
    );
```

How do I render the HTML so it doesn't include all the extra DOM attribute markup (that is, the data-reactid)? I just want to try and save some bits, ya know? I've been reading this related to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html the ReactDomServer, but was wondering if there is an even easier way? If not, how would I integrate that?

Comment: You are rendering the page using react on the server and then transfer it? Why do you?

Comment: Hey @Qwertiy - I'm a total newb to react.js, so I'm not sure what you mean - could you elaborate?

Comment: Your rendering is server-side or client-side?

Comment: we are rendering Client-side

Comment: Than what's the problem with these ids?

Comment: @Qwertiy well it just makes the markup look ugly imo and creates more stuff I don't need

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup`.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostaticmarkup):

> Similar to renderToString, except this doesn't create extra DOM attributes such as data-react-id, that React uses internally. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes can save lots of bytes.

This only makes a difference if you're rendering *on the server*. Also, this markup won't be compatible with React, so it's really only useful for display only Components.

However, this statement you made confuses me:

> How do I render the HTML so it doesn't include all the extra DOM attribute markup (that is, the data-reactid)? I just want to try and save some bits, ya know?

If you're trying to save bits, you don't do it *on the client* (which is where React runs), you do it on the server so that you transfer fewer bits down to the client. Once the app is running on the client's browser, you don't really need to worry about the extra memory that those DOM attributes take up (which are literally the only bits you'd be saving).

Comment: so unless i'm on the server (where I can use those methods), I can't really remove those react ids? Or to ask it another way, if I'm on the client side is there any react methods that can help remove it? Just curious

Comment: If you use `ReactDOM.render`, no you can't remove it. If you use `ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup` (which returns a string), you will have to set the `innerHTML` of the target element yourself, and it will be a purely static element, meaning you will lose all the benefit of React at that point.

Answer (score 9):

Don't worry about it - as of React version `0.15.0-alpha.1`, there's only `data-reactroot` attribute on root node.

Comment: Yes... Even i got confused with only one attribute !!! n i was searching everywhere.. did i miss something :-)